# Why isn't my CSS code not working for Meta Frontend Assignment?

Tags: css

These are the instructions:

Follow the Step by Step instructions below:

1. Open the `styles.css` file.
2. Add a CSS rule for the `body` element that sets the background color to `#E0E0E2`.
3. Add a CSS rule for the `h1` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
4. Add a CSS rule for the `h2` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
5. Add a CSS rule for the `center-text` CSS class that aligns the text to `center`.
6. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `logo`. Set its left and right margins to `auto` and changes its display to a `block` element.
7. Add a CSS rule for all `span` elements that are children of `h2` elements that sets the text color to `#FA9F42` and its font size to `0.75em`.
8. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `copyright`. Set its top padding to `12` pixels and its font size to `0.75em`

```css
body{
    background-color:#E0E0E2;
}
h1{
    color: #721817;
}
h2{
    color: #721817;
}
.center-text{
text-align: center;
}
#logo{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
#span {
    color: #FA9F42;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
#copyright {
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Provide a [mcve] please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

```
body{
background-color:#E0E0E2;
 }

h1{
color: #721817;
 }

h2{
color: #721817;
}

.center-text{
text-align: center;
}

#logo{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
}

h2 > span {
color: #FA9F42;
font-size: 0.75em;
}

#copyright {
padding-top: 12px;
font-size: 0.75em;
 }
```

The span is a child of the h2 hence it must be done this `h2 > span`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!!

Use this. You'll get 100%.

```
h2 > span{
color: #FA9F42;
font-size: 0.75em
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked! They need to improve that grading system.

Answer (score 1):

> Add a CSS rule for all span elements that are children of h2 elements that sets the text color to #FA9F42 and its font size to 0.75em.

In your css set #span , but in your assignment need set for all span in h2

```
h2 span { color... }
```

Comment: This is what I need to fix according to the grader...                                                                   ✗ The 'NEW' labels within <h2> tags should have a color of '#fa9f42' (+ 1 related test)
✗ The element with the ID 'copyright' should have a font-size of 0.75em

Answer (score -1):

### **all test casese passed **

```css
body{
    background-color:#e0e0e2;
}
h1{
    color: #721817;
}
h2{
    color: #721817;
}
.center-text{
text-align: center;
}
#id{
    display: block;
}
#copyright {
padding-top: 12px;
font-size: 0.75em;
 }
h2 > span{ 
    color: #fa9f42; 
    font-size: 0.75em 
}
#logo{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Little Lemon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="center-text">
        <h1>Our Menu</h1>
        <h2>Falafel <span>NEW</span></h2>
        <p>Chickpea, herbs, spices.</p>
        <h2>Pasta Salad</h2>
        <p>Pasta, vegetables, mozzarella.</p>
        <h2>Fried Calamari</h2>
        <p>Squid, buttermilk.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center-text">
        <p id="copyright">
            Copyright Little Lemon
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```